# Using pandas to_datetime in custom function

Tags: python, pandas, date

I am having issues with applying a custom function to a column of a data frame in Python. When I try to apply the function to the column of interest, I receive the following error: *"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'Timestamp' and 'Timestamp'"*

This error is misleading to me as both of the data types appear to be similar. Any idea on what is causing the issue?

```
import pandas as pd

game_df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ["20151030", "20151219", "20191201"]})

game_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(game_df['date'], format = "%Y%m%d")


def nba_season(dt):
    if dt >= pd.to_datetime(2015-10-27) & dt <= pd.to_datetime(2016-6-19):
        return "15_16"
    else:
        return "other"


print(game_df['date'].apply(nba_season))
```

Coming from R, I feel like dates in Python are a little trickier to work with. Is there a better way to approach dates in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting specifies exactly what the issue is.

> unsupported **operand types** for **&**

`&` is a bitwise operator which `Sets each bit to 1 if both bits are 1`

You should use `and` for your use case.

```
if dt >= pd.to_datetime(2015-10-27) and dt <= pd.to_datetime(2016-6-19):
```

Have a read up [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp) on Python operators.

---

You can use the inbuilt `datetime` module to do your comparison.

```
from datetime import datetime

def nba_season(dt):
    if dt >= datetime(2015, 10, 27) and dt <= datetime(2016, 6, 19):
        return "15_16"
    else:
        return "other"
```

Returns:

```
>>> print(game_df['date'].apply(nba_season))
0    15_16
1    15_16
2    other
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Comment: The function works with "and" as the operator, however the returned values don't appear to be working correctly for dates that are within the the specified date range in the function. I apologize for not giving an example of this in my initial data frame. Please use this as the data frame values... game_df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ["20151030", "20151219", "20191201"]})

Comment: Modified answer @mf17